# AWS Cognito Developer authenticated identities process implementation server side

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Case: We have a web application in place with its own authentication process. Now we need to develop mobile application. In order to protect the AWS resources from direct access we have decided to use AWS Cognito. Now I have chosen to go ahead with Developer authenticated identities. What should be the strategy to implement the same on Backend service - using NodeJs